# Html tags are mixing up

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to html. I am trying to attached multiple html page on the server (in the memory) and send it back as one page to client (asp.net mvc 3) but my html source tags are mixing up with each other (resulting into wrong layout) if one of my html source content has not closed the tags properly and does something funny with its layout.

How can I do this such that each html content is displayed independent from other html contents one after each other?

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I have no control over the source html content that I need to attach together so it the source html is wrong, it will come to me wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of having separate documents, fetched by separate HTTP requests all viewed in (i)frames — you can't.

Write code that doesn't output invalid HTML instead.

Comment: I would have done that if that was the case! I should have mentioned that I have no control over the source html content that I need to attached together. Any solution for that?

Comment: Yes. Clean it up. Take the broken code as input, generate valid output. Find an HTML parser that can handle bad input (quite a lot can), make a DOM with it, convert the DOM back to HTML.

Comment: I am new to html so bare with me! I can not manually fix every html that I get. It is hundred and hundred of them that changes on a daily basis. Is there any library that can automatically fix them for .NET?

Comment: My previous comment described how to do it. I can't recommend a specific HTML parser library for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to html and have dealt with this kind of problem simply by changing my code editor.  Try using one that highlights the start and the end of the html tag. Personally I use Komodo IDE or Notepad++.